# lodepng is printing a `1` to cout, how to stop it?

Tags: c++, png

I'm loading `png` files int memory using the [lodepng](http://lodev.org/lodepng/) library. When I call the function `lodepng::decode(vector<...>, uint, uint, string)` to load a file, a `1` magically appears in the console if the load was successful and a `0` if it wasn't. How do I prevent this from happening? Looking through the source there doesn't seem to be anywhere that could print what I described.

I compiled the library myself and used the default Visual Studio 2013 Release build settings, and did not define any macros myself.

Comment: A super hacky way would be to temporarily redirect std::cout to somewhere else.

Comment: @MorphingDragon, well in the end i'm not going to use `cout` at all, but for now I'd like to know how to prevent this.

Comment: After a quick grok of the source code I see what you mean by the number magically appearing.

Comment: @MorphingDragon I'll just debug it by hand sometime, i was just hoping someone would say "just use the LODEPNG_NO_RANDOM_ONES flag to solve your issue!"

Comment: have you asked the library creator.

Comment: @MorphingDragon I didn't think of that, but it seems unnecessary. I'll keep it as an option though!

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour with the current version of `lodepng.h` and `lodepng.cpp`. You would have to add your code/settings used to create your library and the code for the decoding to the question. Are you sure your code or library isn't outputting anything?

Comment: @uesp I'll take a look, and I am sure I'm not outputting anything.

Answer (score 2):

Got it, I guess I never posted the version I was using, but i'm using version `2014-08-23`, and the `load_file` function has a `printf("%i", bool(file));` line which is obviously the culprit. The latest version does not have this line.